# Getting the 2nd layer to stay closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my page I have a nav bar. In my nav bar I have 3 levels. The first layer is the main menu and then you get the second layer and then the third. My problem is that when I hover over the menu item that has the children both the 2nd level and 3rd level is shown, but I only want the 2nd level to show unless I hover over the 2nd level that has a 3rd level.

Here is my menu

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default main_menu">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<div class="navbar-header">
<div id="mainMenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="parent">
Home
<ul class="father"> </ul>
</li>
<li class="parent">
About Layer 1
<ul class="father">
<li class="parent_child">
About Layer 2
<ul class="son" style="display: none;">
<li class="child"> About Layer 3 part 2 </li>
<li class="child"> About Layer 3 Part 3 </li>
<li class="child"> About Layer 3 Part 4 </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="parent_child">
About Layer 2 part 2
<ul class="son">
<li class="child"> About Layer 3 </li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="parent">
Test
<ul class="father">
<li class="parent_child">
test 2
<ul class="son" style="display: none;">
<li class="child"> test 3 </li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

My js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".nav a").click(function(){
    //event.preventDefault();
    $(".nav a").removeClass("active-menu");
    $(this).addClass("active-menu");
});

$('ul.navbar-nav li').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('.father:first').css('display','block');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('.father:first').css('display','none');  
    }
);

$('ul.navbar-nav li').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('.son:first').css('display','block');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('.son:first').css('display','none');  
    }
);
});
```

My css

```
.father{
display: none;
}

.son{
display: none;
}
```

The Jsfiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8otgg97t/)

Comment: Perhaps changing the selector with the `.hover()` method from `ul.navbar-nav li` to `ul.navbar-nav > li` or something like `ul > li` is a useful hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your jQuery to the following:

The [`.children()` method](http://api.jquery.com/children/) will only select direct `ul` children:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/p7u92ehL/)

```
$('ul.navbar-nav li').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).children('ul').show();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).children('ul').hide();
    }
);
```

Alternatively, you could also use the [direct child selector, `>`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
$('ul.navbar-nav li').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('> ul').show();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('> ul').hide();
    }
);
```

---

It's worth pointing out that you can avoid jQuery completely, and use pure CSS:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/gwakrmer/)

```
ul.navbar-nav li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul.navbar-nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```